# What is the best way to restrict /proc fs from malicious users (linux)?

Tags: linux, file-system, kernel, process

I am trying to make a restriction to procfs like only a certain groups of members can perform read and write actions.

[kernel document](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) says we can do that by setting `hidepid` and `gid` in `/etc/fstab`. It will restrict the malicious user from making read and write on procfs but I have a doubt whether it is possible for malicious user (restricted in the `/etc/fstab`) to access content in profs using `syscall` instead of `fs operation` like read and write.

Comment: What end specifically are you trying to prevent malicious users from doing? Accessing /proc isn't the end; it's the means to the end.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica there is multiple end. for example you can take malicious user should not read other users cmdline value which will be in `/proc/<id>/cmdline` or you can also take malicious user should not read other users environ value which will be in `/proc/<id>/environ`.

Comment: Why do you think `hidepid=2` isn't good enough to stop that?

Comment: Yes while reading it sounds good, but I need to double-check is this option is sufficient. Is there any other way a malicious user can view the `environment value (environ)` of other users using syscall or any other way?

Comment: Why do you think `hidepid` isn't effective against syscalls, when they're the normal way to read from there?

Comment: Hmm, this is because I have no in-depth knowledge about procfs. Are you sure `hidepid` is sufficient?

Comment: Why not just set hidepid and then try it?

Answer (score 1):

In general, `hidepid` mentioned in the comments is the best way.

If you need more security than that, use a mandatory access control system like SELinux or AppArmor, and possibly systrace. These tools let you restrict file system access, syscalls and more. I think most of the info in /proc is not available from syscalls, but I'm not up-to-date on this.

MAC tools are not "click and go" solutions and require quite a lot of work to configure. Before you embark on this, have a think about whether this is the best way to invest your security resources.